# Symfony 2: "No route found for "GET /" - error on fresh installation

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to begin my education of symfony 2 and started with it's tutorial. One of first things I tried was to install symfony 2 and configure it.

When I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I am getting an incomplete site with the following error:

> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at /home/spectator/webprojects/cls/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2059

Things I have tried so far:

- clearing cache (`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`)
- recursively changing permissions to folder cls (symfony 2 folder) to
  `775` and even `777` (for diagnostics purposes)
- adding "/" route to routing.yml and routing_dev.yml
- reinstalling and
- re-chmod symfony 2.

Comment: Fresh installation would most likely means that you're using at least @2.7 version of Symfony. If that's correct your routing should be configured to use annotations by default if you haven't changed that. Open your DefaultController and search for `@Route()` annotation.

Comment: Yes, to be more specific it is v2.7.1. DefaultController? I can't find this file anywhere in "cls" folder.

Comment: You should have a directory named `src`. This is where your bundles get defined. Inside it you should have your default bundle - as of @2.6 or @2.7 it's called `AppBundle`. Inside is a folder `Controller` where you can find your DefaultController.

Comment: DefaultController.php, yes, i found it now, thx. I will check it.

Comment: I opened a bug for this a few weeks ago as it's quite misleading for new users following the quick start guide to receive an error as almost the first thing they do: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5353

Comment: BT643, thanks for reporting a bug to them. You are right on this and i can confirm it with experience, as you can see in this thread. I came to their guide to learn this framework and first thing i have to do is not to code some first samples after up to few hours of reading but instead i'm posting error messages and googling for solution. I really hope they will fix it and newcomers will have easier than i do. Now i found out by myself that i just have to read half of tutorial to know wtf am i doing and how to fix something what they messed up. Learning curve lvl master achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://localhost:8000/app/example

Fresh installation has no routes for the root path "/"

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer which is more workaround than solution and to be honest there is no real solution to this problem as this is just horrible failure in design of tutorial. Anyway, this should be put in tutorial instead of http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set a default route 
edit the routing.yml 
    app/config/routing.yml

```
app:
resource: @AppBundle/Controller/  # bundle name / Controller name
type:     annotation  # type of routing or 
# app/config/routing.yml   # file routing 


app: 
resource: @AppBundle/Controller/ 
prefix: /
```

you can learn more in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: That's what i hate in some tutorials: to begin you need to get knowledge from few chapters further :D It seems like i need to do some routing, will try to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The default installation does not come with a default route for "/".

The example controller only defines a route of

```
@Route("/app/example", name="homepage")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, a fresh Symfony installation also included some simple demo code to learn how does the framework work. A few months ago we decided to change this behavior by the following:

1. A fresh Symfony installation no longer contains any demo code.
2. A new "Symfony Demo Application" has been published for people learning the framework ([read more](http://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-demo-application) about this demo application).

If you use the [Symfony Installer](http://symfony.com/download), you should do the following:

1. When learning Symfony, execute the `symfony demo` command
2. When creating a new Symfony project, execute the `symfony new my_project` command

Comment: This should be changed back to its previous state or at least official guide should be properly edited otherwise there will be more newcomers confused the same way as i was.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Just add `<?php` in the top of the file. Looks like if we don't specify it s

Comment: Add in the top of the file <?php

Comment: you can edit your answer and add the missing part of your sentence :-) BTW: have a look at the formatting help to learn how to format code snippets (select and ctrl-k helps)